# How to find the content of a URL in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a URL. Now I want to find out the content of the URL.  By content of the URL I mean whether the URL contains a html page, video or an image/photo.  How can I do this in asp.net with c#.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to do a HEAD request with `HttpWebRequest`:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "HEAD";
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    // Here, examine the response headers.
    // In particular response.ContentType
}
```

In some cases, HEAD might give you a 405 error, meaning that the server doesn't support HEAD.

In that case, just do a GET request (change `req.Method = "GET"`). That will start to download the page, but you can still view the content type header.

Comment: Except for content embeded (such as youtube controls or photo gallery). A head is only good when you're interrogating a direct url-to-content request, not a page with mixed content therein.

Comment: @BradChristie: Yes, a Web resource can be arbitrarily complex, requiring multiple requests and considerable processing to determine the *real* content. This is the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Probably start off using a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and visit/download the page. Then use an [HTML parser](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), and whatever method you deem best, to determine what kind of content is on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Except from following the link, fetching the result and figuring out from the file content what file it is (which is rather tricky), there is no fool proof way.

You can try to determine from the file extension or the returned `content-type` header (you can issue a `HEAD` request) what the type should be. This will tell you what the server *claims* the file type to be.

Answer (score 0):

For easier testing, this is a console application, but it should work with ASP.NET all the same:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  using System;
  using System.Net;

  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      //var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com"); // page will result in html/text
      var request = WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.google.de/logos/2013/douglas_adams_61st_birthday-1062005.2-res.png");

      request.Method = "HEAD"; // only request header information, don't download the whole file

      var response = request.GetResponse();

      Console.WriteLine(response.ContentType);

      Console.WriteLine("Done.");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```